# Linux command for finding unique file contents in many text files

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a bunch of files displaying error messages, each of which has a traceback. Many of these have the same error message, and I'd like to have a list of all unique error messages in every file. How do I find the set of unique file contents?

EDIT: To clarify, each file contains a traceback from Python, so these are multi-line files that I'd like to find the unique set of.

Comment: One error per line, or multiline errors?

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified that in an edit above. They're multiline errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "a bunch" of files, `find` and `xargs` are the tools to use.
 Your problem needs `grep`, `sort` and `uniq`, too

If all your error messages look like "`Error: blah blah`" at the beginning of the line (you should have said), this will do it:

```
find . -type f -print0 |\
  xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty grep --no-filename "^Error:" |\
    sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

The last line is a well known expression for counting unique occurrences. The first `sort` groups all of the same message together, `uniq -c` outputs only unique lines, prefaced by a count (`-c`), the the last `sort -rn` sorts by the numbers, in reverse order.

```
for readthis in find xargs grep sort uniq ; do
    man $readthis
done
```